# Rotor removal help

Tags: honda, brake-rotor, crv

I have a 2005 CRV the rotor will not come off.  I have tried almost everything. I say almost as there must be something else.

I have beaten the rotor like it stole my rent money.  I have tried using two bolts, four nuts and two washers.  I have tried using an extractor to remove it.  The rotor is covered in WD-40 and PB blaster; it's literally dripping.

I don't know what else to do. I have tried everything but heat, and I don't want to risk burning anything important. Please help.

Comment: Two or four wheel drive, front or rear rotors?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say you have tried using two bolts?

Answer (score 2):

Exactly what @Movemorecommentslinktotop said in his comment ... if the rear rotors, there is a second braking surface inside the rotor "hat" which is for the e-brakes. If you haven't backed these shoes off or if you have the e-brake on, you'll never get these off.

The front brakes may be rusted around the hub and are not releasing. They can become "space welded" or rust bonded to this *very* tight area. Make sure you hit this with WD-40 as well.

When you are hitting the rotor, hit it from side to side (one side then the other). Hitting it on one edge will allow it to become *wedged* and will not move after it. By hitting it from side to side, you are moving it a little bit at a time, but as soon as the center loosens up, it will come off easily. I've also found that beating it *back onto* the hub can sometimes make a difference, in that it loosens things up and allows the rust to release.